# jQuery UI Slider and Min/Max Range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, range

I have a jQuery UI Slider, with the following settings:

```
{
    min: 10,
    max: 400,
    value: 100
}
```

My problem is I want the slider initial state to always be in the middle of the slider, the problem is because of the min/max the slider is always off the left rather than center.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Set the value to 205. That will put it in the middle.

Comment: :) Ya, but then the slider doesn't reflect the actual value.

Comment: I don't understand. You want the slider to be in the middle, even though that's not what the value is? What purpose would this serve other than to confuse the user?

Comment: I think I found an answer ... If you look at http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/ there is a heterogeneity option that allows you to tweak the scale.